# mod_rewrite /p/about => ?p=about

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

i have a specific question concerning mod_rewrite:

when the user calls:

> **www.test.com/p/about**

the webserver should call internally

> **www.test.com/?p=about**

to access subpages of the website.

but in the adress bar it should still say

> **www.test.com/p/about**

is this anyhow possible with mod_rewrite?

**My solutions that did not work out:**

1. Try

> RewriteRule ^/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L] 
>   
>   Wrong effect, because it only works with: test.com/about, but I need test.com/p/about!

1. Try

> RewriteRule ^p/([a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?p=$1
>   
>   Error: it redirects correct but the paths on the html file are wrong: eg. /img/pic.png is now /p/img/pic.png

big thanks,
stee

Comment: Have you checked any of the almost identical question in the right-hand bar?

Comment: Yes it is possible, in fact it's one of the most basic things you can do with `mod_rewrite` - did you have a go at it yourself yet? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Or, as the others have said - check out the duplicates on the right :)

Comment: yes, i've tried many possibilities, i can tell you, its not that easy as it sounds. edited my solution to the initial post that didnt work out.

Comment: any ideas left? i'm really trying to solve this problem, any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible with mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^p/([a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?p=$1
```

Or, more generally:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?$1=$2
```

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: sorry, this indeed redirects me to **test.php?p=about** but the adress in the adressbar also changes to **test.php?p=about** and this is what i want to avoid! so its not so simple as it sounds in first place!

Comment: This rule works fine for me - what does the PHP script you're redirecting to do?

Comment: its a index php-file which displays the corresponding subpage, in this case the about page.